# Magento Catalog Search is not working properly?

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, search, magento-1.8

I am using magento community edition 1.8.1.0 and when i search products it is not returning the correct results.I used an ajax based extension and is it showing correct result in dropdown but when i use view all items ie magento default search it is not working.For example if we search Cummins Onan RV it is showing perfect in dropdown but not in default search it says empty results.Here is my website:
[click here to view my website](http://www.coloradostandby.com)

Please help! Also the seach type in backend is LIKE.I want it same like it is showing in dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try reindexing, log in to your admin, goto `system >> Index Management`, a grid will be shown, you can `select all` and click `submit` button.